# How to use non-blocking http calls for pac4j oauth code/access token exchange

Tags: spring-security, oauth, pac4j

I am using pac4j 5.7 with Spring.

Drilling into the standard flow of pac4j Oauth+code authentication, the http call to validate the code and retrieve an access token is a synchronous call.

```
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(AccessTokenRequestParams params)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    return sendAccessTokenRequestSync(createAccessTokenRequest(params));
}
```

It looks like there are methods within scribejava's OAuth20Service for async calls, but the pac4j OAuth20Authenticator calls the sync version.

Is it possible to configure pac4j to use non-blocking calls?

Answer (score 0):

By design, pac4j only offers sync calls. So this is not possible.